# Interpreting classification report for neural network algorithm

Tags: theory

I'm trying to interpret a classification report from a neural network that predicts mortality by heart failure as below. I can tell that predicting 0 is more accurate than predicting 1based on the f1-scores. However, I'm not sure why there's a fairly big gap between the precision value and recall value for both 0 and 1. Does this mean that my model has to be tuned or the dataset is biased? I would like to know how to proceed from this. Thanks!

[image: classification_report]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sorry about that! I'm still learning about the community!

Comment: No problem; just be sure to keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: Yeb! I will keep this in mind for my future posts! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Let us try to understand this further by looking at this example below.

**Example** - Confusion matrix

[image]

The Precision and recall for each label is given below. It is similar to the figures shown in your example.

[image]

So in the actual dataset, there are **70** records labelled as `1` and **95** records labelled as `0`.

**Confusion Matrix**

[image]

**Precision**

*Precision Formula = True Positives / (True Positives + False Positives)*

In case of label `1`, Out of the 31 which were classified as `1` by the model, 30 were correct and only 1 was incorrect. Hence its precision score is high which is 96.7%

In case of label `0`, Out of the 134 which were classified as `0` by the model, 94 were correct but 40 was incorrect. Hence its precision score is at moderate level of ~70%.

**Recall**

*Recall Formula = True Positives / (True Positives + False Negatives)*

In case of label `1`, Out of the 70 labels that are actually `1`, the model could only identify 30 correctly as `1`. Hence its recall score is low at ~43%.

In case of label `0`, Out of the 95 labels that are actually `0`, the model could identify 94 correctly as `0`. Hence its recall score is high at ~99%.

Now to answer your question on whether you should tune the model depends on what is the result that you are looking for. If you are looking for good precision and recall on both labels, then yes should tune them and get a decent f1-score on both of them. But if you are more concerned about recall than precision, then you should let go of precision and improve recall and viceversa.